# Create multiple Postgres instances on same machine

Tags: postgresql

To test streaming replication, I would like to create a second Postgres instance on the same machine. The idea is that if it can be done on the test server, then it should be trivial to set it up on the two production servers.

The instances should use different configuration files and different data directories. I tried following the instructions here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1431697 but I haven't figured out how to get Postgres to use a different configuration file. If I copy the init script, the scripts are just aliases to the same Postgres instance.

I'm using Postgres 9.3 and the Postgres help pages say to specify the configuration file on the `postgres` command line. I'm not really sure what this means. Am I supposed to install some client for this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Just run `initdb` pointing it to a different data directory (and specify a different port)

Comment: Is `initdb` able to create a database cluster with a custom configuration file? It seems that I can only specify where the data will be stored.

Comment: `initdb` _creates_ the config file (in the data directory)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I assume you can work your way out on using postgresql utilities.

**Create the clusters**

```
$ initdb -D /path/to/datadb1
$ initdb -D /path/to/datadb2
```

**Run the instances**

```
$ pg_ctl -D /path/to/datadb1 -o "-p 5433" -l /path/to/logdb1 start
$ pg_ctl -D /path/to/datadb2 -o "-p 5434" -l /path/to/logdb2 start
```

**Test streaming**

Now you have two instances running on ports 5433 and 5434. Configuration files for them are in data dirs specified by `initdb`. Tweak them for streaming replication.
Your default installation remains untouched in port 5432.

Comment: If you want to use a different config file location you can specify that in the -o string according to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html). Something like `-o "config_file=/path/to/my/postgresql.conf"` (not tested!)

Comment: Thank you! I did a little change in the process: params sent after `-o` are passed to the `postgres` server, so in that way you are setting the port by a command line flag, and the `postgresql.conf` get those changes but not explicitly and probably you would need to change that file after. I think that modifying it first, and then start the server setting that conf file is a better practice. (In the next comment I leave the commands)

Comment: So after `initdb -D /path/to/datadb1` I modified `/path/to/datadb1/postgresql.conf` params `data_directory`, `hba_file`, `ident_file`, `listen_addresses`, `port` (some are optional) and started the server with: 
`pg_ctl -D /path/to/datadb1/ -o "-c config_file=/path/to/datadb1/postgresql.conf" -l /path/to/logdb1.log start`

Answer (score 8):

On Debian based distros you could use `pg_createcluster` instead of `initdb`:

```
$ pg_createcluster -u [user] -g [group] -d /path/to/data -l /path/to/log -p 5433
```

Also `pg_ctlcluster` is an alternative to `pg_ctl`.

Answer (score 8):

Steps to create New Server Instance on PostgreSQL 9.5

1. On command prompt run:

   ```
   initdb -D Instance_Directory_path -U username -W
   ```

   (prompts for password)
2. Once the new Instance Directory is created. Run command prompt as Administrator

   ```
   pg_ctl register -N service_name -D Instance_Directory_path -o "-p port_no"
   ```
3. After the service is registered, start server

   ```
   pg_ctl start -D Instance_Directory_path -o "-p port_no"
   ```

Comment: `pg_ctl register` only on **windows**.

Answer (score 1):

To complete other answers, on **CentOS 6 AND 7**.

After running something like

```
$ initdb -D /path/to/newdb
```

You'll have to change at least `port` configuration option and, probably, `listen_addresses` in config file `postgresql.conf`.

Instead of starting inmediatly this new instance, which has been explained in previous answers, maybe you want new instance to run automatically on system start (in case of shutdown, e.g.). To do this, as CentOS doesn't have `pg_ctl register` option (only for Windows) you'll have to create a new service file and register it in order systemctl or service can start it up automatically.

- **Centos 6**

Follow next commands to get service's init file:

```
[root@machine ~]# service postgresql-9.6 edit
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.6 {start|stop|status|restart|upgrade|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|initdb|promote}
[root@machine ~]# cd /etc/init.d          # Now we know where service file is
[root@machine init.d]# cp -p postgresql-9.6 postgresql-9.6_5433
[root@machine init.d]# vi postgresql-9.6_5433
```

Now you can change `PGDATA` directory with the one where new instance resides. If you're using Postgresql version previous to 9.4 (which you shouldn't by the time of this answer) you'll have to change `PGPORT` too with the value where new instance is listening to.

The name of the new service is up to you. I usually take original service name and add port number at the end.

Now you only have to register new service:

```
[root@machine init.d]# chkconfig postgresql-9.6_5433 on        # service registered!
[root@machine init.d]# service postgresql-9.6_5433 start
Iniciando servicios postgresql-9.6_5433:                   [  OK  ]
[root@machine init.d]# service postgresql-9.6_5433 status
Se está ejecutando postgresql-9.6_5433 (pid  120993)...
```

- **Centos 7**

In CentOS 7 instead of `service` to control services running on the machine you have `systemctl` and commands and paths change a bit. But the process is the same: create new service file, edit with the new location/port, register and start:

```
[root@localhost ~]# locate postgresql.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postgresql.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
[root@localhost ~]# cp -p postgresql.service postgresql_5433.service
[root@localhost ~]# vi postgresql_5433.service
# Change PGDATA and maybe PGPORT if PG version <9.4
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable postgresql_5433.service
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start postgresql_5433.service
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl list-unit-files | grep postgres
postgresql.service                                 enabled 
postgresql_5433.service                            enabled
```