# How to run 2 PostgreSQL servers on localhost?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to run 2 database server on the same machine(localhost). default port is 5432..Is there a way to change it? I create a second cluster and edited the "postgresql.conf" file to change port to 5434 and restart the server but IPV4 and IPV6 are still showing a connection on port 5432. Anyone can help ?

thanks

Comment: why are you tagging python, remove unrelated tags

Comment: also add some details about your operating system - this is a system management question more than PostgreSQL related. Debian or ubuntu make this trivial, others make it harder.

Comment: If you are actually running two instances there will be one listening on 5432 and one on 5434, so connections on port 5432 would not be surprising.

Comment: The OS is openSuse 42.3 with psql 9.3 and Python 2.7, not my choice but this is what I have to work with. I tagged Python 2.7 because I have to do a database replication script using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it:
[Create multiple Postgres instances on same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861262/create-multiple-postgres-instances-on-same-machine)

pg_ctl -D full/path/to/myCluster -o -pXXXX start

Where -D folder where the cluster is
Where -o is for command line options to pass to postgres
where -pXXXX is the port number you want to connect. You choose any port not taken by another process